# If statement inside a function "stopping" code in Command Line program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

I am writing a function for a command line program that I intend to use at work for myself. I am very new to python and can't seem to find others that have the same issue as me anywhere online. When I get to the end of my 'if' statement if my input is 'y' or 'Y' the code in the program stops until I hit 'enter' and then it moves on to the next code block as intended. If my response falls under the 'else' category, the code performs the else block of code and moves on as intended. Why is my code not moving on in the 'if' section but moves on just find if input falls under the 'else' section. Hopefully that makes sense. Below I will post my function. Thank you.

```
def vct_choice():
    vct_flooring = input("Is there any VCT on this job? (Y/N): ")
    f.write("\n" "Is there any VCT on this job? (Y/N): ")
    f.write(vct_flooring)
    f.write("\n")
    print("\n")

    if vct_flooring == 'y' or vct_flooring == 'Y':
        f.write("\n")
        total_vct_sf = int(input("Please enter the total SF of VCT needed, 
        minus any waste: "))
        print("\n")
        print(vct_boxes + str(int(total_vct_sf * 1.1 // 45 + 1 + 5)))
        print("\n")
        print(vct_glue + str(int(total_vct_sf // 1200 + 1)))
        f.write("Please enter the total SF of VCT needed, minus any waste: 
        ")
        f.write(input () )
        f.write (str(total_vct_sf))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(vct_boxes + str(int(total_vct_sf * 1.1 // 45 + 1 + 5)))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(str(vct_glue))
        f.write(str(int(total_vct_sf // 1200 + 1)))
        f.write("\n")
        print("\n")
        print("\n") 

    else:
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("No VCT Needed")
        f.write("\n")
        print("No VCT Needed")
        print("\n")
```

Comment: your function has bad indentation

Comment: Whoops. good catch, let me fix that.

Comment: `if if vct_flooring in "y Y":` would be a replacer for your if ... or ... : which should work as well

Comment: What is `f`, and why do you write input prompts to it?

Comment: this: `f.write(input () )` waits for an input - after wich the rest of your if-clause is processed... and written into the file

Comment: @chepner the f is a file that I have open in my code already. im writing all the questions and inputs into the file for recording purposes so i can print it out later

Comment: @PatrickArtner this actually worked. all I had to do was delete that input line. I thought I needed it when i really didnt. Thanks!

Comment: As Patrick Artner already commented, you code is stopping because it's waiting for input in the line `f.write(input())`. You only wrote the prompt for that input to `f`, not to standard output as well. There's nothing after that line that would cause your code to block.

Comment: Otherwise the problem is probably outside the code you are showing. Somewhere near where you call your function.  Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @PatrickArtner see my original comment. I deleted the input that you suggested and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: voting to close as typo :)

Comment: Also, no clue why I cant mark your answer as the correct one. The usual green checkmark isn't there for me.

Comment: Cale - it is a comment, no answer ;) Creating an answer that tells you : remove that line - has not much worth for SO unless someone creates the same code as you and is very lucky to find your post ;) simply delete it if you can work on...